# Access a inheritated variable from anon class in Java

Tags: java, android, inheritance, abstract, extends

As the title says, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
public abstract class ClassA{

    private String var;

    ...


    protected void setVar(String var){
        this.var = var
    };

    protected String getVar(){
        return this.var
    };  
}

public class ClassB extends ClassA{

    public ClassB(...){

        object.setListener(new Listener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(data ...){
                // Would like to do:
                var = data;
                // BUT:
                // CANT CALL VAR since its a private String of Class A
                // CANT CALL setVar(data) since it will end up looping
                // CANT CALL super.setVar(data) since super dosn't point to ClassA in here
            };
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void setVar(String var){
        super.setVar(var);

        // DO MORE STUFF WHICH WILL CALL THE LISTENER
    };
}
```

Sure, I could make var public, but that's not what I want! var should remain protected, changes should only happen using the setters.

Is there a way?

Comment: because setVar would call the setVar method of ClassB. If you look at the comment i wrote in setVar in ClassB you see that indeed it would call super.setVar and therefore set the var in ClassA BUT setVar from ClassB does some actions which cause the onItemSelected listener to be called which would then call setVar from ClassB again and so on. You would end up looping. The only chance i see to come over this issue and keep var private is to use a different method name for the method which calls super.setVar within ClassB. But that's kinda ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
object.setListener(new Listener(){
public void onItemSelected(data ...){
    ClassB.this.var = data;
}});
```

Comment: Thanks that did it! However, can you explain what this does exacly? I mean, how is it possible that i access the current instance of ClassB from a anon class with this? Is it specially designed to get access from anon classes?

Comment: Whenever you try to reference a member variable from within a class the the `this` pointer to is inferred. I.E. `this.var` is the same as `var`, however in this case `var` is not a member of the `Listener` class but an enclosing class `ClassB`. So you have to specify which `this` pointer you want to use to do that you give the class name first.

Comment: thanks! makes sense. i edited my first question a bit since i had a error in it. i want var to be private and only accessable using setters getters (see edited code sample). now this trick dosn't work anymore. HOWEVER since IN THIS special case my ClassA didn't need a implementation of setVar i just made that setter abstract and made var protected. using a adapted package structure i've been able to protect var from access i don't want. BUT what if i would want var to be private?

Comment: If the variable is private then you won't be able to access it and you'll have to use a public or protected getter/setter

Answer (score -1):

A little convoluted, but:

```
class Listener {
    public void onItemSelected(String data){ }
}

class ClassC {
    public void setListener(Listener listen) {
        listen.onItemSelected("Do something");
    }
}

abstract class ClassB{

    protected String var;

    protected void setVar(String var){
        this.var = var;
    };

    protected String getVar(){
        return this.var;
    };  

    public void printVar() {
        System.out.println("This is 'var': " + this.var);
    }
}

public class ClassA extends ClassB{

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        ClassA me = new ClassA("Do something else");
    }

    public ClassA(String x){

        ClassC object = new ClassC();
        object.setListener(new Listener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(String data){
                // Would like to do:
                var = data;
                // BUT:
                // CANT CALL VAR since its a protected String of Class A
                // CANT CALL setVar(data) since it will end up looping
                // CANT CALL super.setVar(data) since super dosn't point to ClassA in here
            };
        });
        this.printVar();
   }

    @Override
    protected void setVar(String var){
        super.setVar(var);

        // DO MORE STUFF WHICH WILL CALL THE LISTENER
    };
}
```

Results:

```
C:\JavaTools>javac ClassA.java

C:\JavaTools>java ClassA
This is 'var': Do something

C:\JavaTools>
```